# Collecting examples of all rings R such that $x^3=x \forall x \in R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

1. $\mathbb{Z_{3}}$ or its Cartesian products..
2. The Boolean ring R which is defined as a ring in which every element is idempotent, that is $ \forall x \in R$ we have $x^2=x$ and hence $x^3=x^2x=xx=x$ in fact here $x^n=x$ ..

Any more???
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: HINT: The only domains satisfying this condition are the field with three elements and the field with two elements. Moreover, if $R$ is such a ring, and $I$ is any ideal of $R$, then $R/I$ satisfies the same condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start out by saying we'll assume you believe [Jacobson's famous theorem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969205?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) which proves such a ring is commutative.

The condition that $x^3=x$ implies three things:

1. There are non nonzero nilpotent elements, so the intersection of all prime ideals is zero; and
2. Every prime ideal is maximal, and moreover given a prime ideal $P$, $R/P$ is isomorphic to the field of two or three elements; and
3. The Jacobson radical is zero (this is just a combination of the last two points.)

The first one I hope is obvious, and the second one is clear when you look at $R/P$ for a prime ideal $P$: the equation $0=x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$ in the field of fractions of $R/P$ has exactly three solutions $\{0, 1, -1\}$, and all of those happen to be in $R/P$ already. So the quotient is either the field of two elements $F_2$ or the field of three elements $F_3$, and $P$ is maximal.

Now we can form the product ring $S=\prod R/M$ where $M$ ranges over the complete set of maximal ideals of $R$ (or just a subset of the maximals whose intersection is zero, if you like), and we see it is a (potentially infinite) product ring of copies of $F_2$ and/or $F_3$. Now, there is the diagonal mapping $r\mapsto (\ldots,r+M ,\ldots)$. The Jacobson radical is the kernel of this mapping, so we have actually shown that $R$ injects into a ring like $S$.

It also should be obvious that any subring of a ring like $S$ satisfies $x^3=x$.

This proves that the set of rings (with identity) satisfying $x^3=x$ is exactly the class of subrings of rings of the form $\prod_{i\in I} F_i$ where $F_i\in \{F_2, F_3\}$ and $I$ is an index set.

One interesting case occurs when the set of maximal ideals is finite: the diagonal map mentioned above is onto by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and therefore you ring is isomorphic to a finite product of copies of $F_2$ and/or $F_3$.